# Sitecore 7.1 Grid Designer and adding a control

Tags: grid, sitecore, windows-forms-designer, sitecore7.1

I am new to Sitecore and have questions. I have installed Sitecore version 7.1 several times just for the fun of it, sweet.   Now, I am attempting to follow a tutorial of “Building A Very Simple Website”

http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/training%20materials/basic%20site/selfstudyguide-buildingaverysimplewebsite_usletter.pdf

This tutorial is targeted for Sitecore CMS 6.2, so I want to confirm if it’s still accurate.
The instructions for creating a Generic sublayout display file says I should be able to access the Grid Designer and insert a control while in the Content Editor.   I am not seeing any option for this.  The only way for me to access the Grid Designer, is by selecting /Development Tools/Development Center.  And when I do this I can insert a control but it’s not saving any of my changes.

As anybody had this problem?
Is that tutorial still valid?

Answer (score 5):

I had this same question. I'm running sitecore 7.1 but am following an outdated self study guide for sitecore 6.2. I was able to resolve doing the following.

1. From the Desktop interface, open the start menu
2. Open Development Center (Listed under Development Tools)
3. Select 'Create New Sublayout'
4. Once created the options you seek will be available

This is the start page for the Developer Center
[image: Developer Center Start Page]

This will open automatically when you finish the Sublayout creation wizard
[image: Sublayout edit screen with Add Toolbar]

Comment: Also, to continue with next steps per that guide, ensure upon creating the new sublayout that the option to 'Create Associated C# Code Files' is selected

Answer (score 2):

The grid designer is still there. It relates to `Sublayouts`, so if you go to `/sitecore/layout/Sublayouts` and select one of the sublayout items, you should then see the grid designer tab:

[image]

Towards the top right of the screen you should see some tabs for dislaying `layout` and `format` options:

[image]

To be honest, you'll rarely (if ever) use the grid designer again after this tutorial, so don't worry to much.

Comment: Are you certain your version is 7.1 because the grid designer seems to have been deprecated?

Comment: You're right. It's seems I was using 7.0. Here are the release notes for 7.1, which state that the tab has been removed. http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog/Release%20History%20SC71.aspx Sorry for the misleading answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with Sitecore 8 and solved it creating Sub Layout,going though development center as shown above by @Tyshun. Else

1. Go direct to development Center using url `http://{{Your Site Name}}/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=IDE`.
2. You will get option to create SubLayout and then you will get grid view design option.